# showing submit query after deleting the image from datalist

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I have the following code and some images listed in a [`DataList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx):

```
protected void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Id != 0)
    {
    BaseClass.Delete(Id1);
    string path = Path.Combine(GetDirectory(Name), Name);
        File.Delete(path);
    }
}

public void BindImages()
{
    path = BaseClass.GetAllImages(PId);
    for (int i = 0; i < path.Count; i++)
    {
        ArrayList lst = path[i];
        tb.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(lst[0]), lst[1].ToString(), 
                                                 lst[2].ToString(), i);
    }
    dlst1.DataSource = tb;
    dlst1.DataBind();
}
```

When I click on the delete button for an image the image is removed but when I rebind the `DataList` the images are being duplicated.

I am binding the `DataList` in my `PageLoad` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `IsPostBack` boolean property in the Page_Load handler.

```
protected void page_load()
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
   {
     BindImages();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't keep BindImages in side the !IsPostPack, its will effect other functionality.

Comment: @Rocky - Remove all rows from the tb (DataTable object) before the for loop in BindImages() method or instantiate the DataTable object within this method.